# How to return specific number or rows in with SQL Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is a difficult question to articulate so bare with me if it is a little confusing.

I have sales data split over a few tables that I would like to summarise in a SQL pivot.
The script that I have put together so far will return the the summarised sales data per customer, per stock group and pivot is on a date period (0 - 4) and summed on the sales value.

The 6 stock groups are Stationery, Cartridges, Paper, Groceries, Janitorial and Other.

If the customer being queried only bought items in 3 of the groups then it will return 3 rows with the applicable data.

What I want to achieve is that it returns 6 rows and the other 3 don't have any values in the sum.

The script I have so far is as follows:

```
SELECT * from (
    SELECT
        c.DCLink, 
        c.Account AS [AccountCode], 
        c.Name AS [AccountName],
        r.userid,
        IIF(CHARINDEX('-', g.[Description]) > 0, LEFT(g.[Description], CHARINDEX('-', g.[Description])-2),'Other') AS [Group], 
        ps.Credit - ps.Debit AS TransAmt, 
        DATEDIFF(month, ps.TxDate, GETDATE()) AS Period
    FROM
        [db1].dbo.PostST AS ps
        INNER JOIN [db2].dbo.UserRepLink r ON ps.RepID = r.repid 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [db1].dbo.Client c ON ps.DrCrAccount = c.DCLink 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [db1].dbo._etblStockDetails AS sd 
        INNER JOIN [db1].dbo.StkItem AS si ON sd.StockID = si.StockLink 
        INNER JOIN [db1].dbo.GrpTbl AS g ON sd.GroupID = g.idGrpTbl ON ps.AccountLink = si.StockLink

    WHERE        
        (ps.Id = 'OInv' OR ps.Id = 'Crn') AND (ps.TxDate >= DATEADD(Month, DATEDIFF(Month, 0, DATEADD(m, - 4, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)), 0)) and DCLink = 187
) AS sourceTable 

PIVOT (
    SUM(sourceTable.TransAmt)
    FOR sourceTable.[Period] IN ([0],[1],[2],[3],[4])
) AS SalesPiv
```

[This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clMxG.png)

However

[This is the desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqSQm.png)

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest that you create an inner query that has all the categories and then outer join with your current query this will give you the missing categories.

Let me know if you need further information

Comment: This is a comment - not an answer

Comment: This results in this method will result in it adding the Groups to the list but will however have null values on the other fields as well.

Comment: @Darren Looking at the desired result image in your question it is showing NULL.